# Is there any tool to reproject x,y coordinates, apart from Proj4?

Tags: coordinate-system, java

I have a JEE project (Java, JBoss) and I'm looking for a library that allows x,y coordinates reprojection.

I know about Proj4. Do you have any other option?

Is it possible to find on the net a reprojection algorithm that I could use?

The reprojection I'm interest in is the French NTF Lambert II Etendu to RGF Lambert 93.

Comment: Have a look at Geotools and deegree. They both support projection transformations in native java.

Comment: Thanks @user30184 Geotools is too heavy installing 200Mo for just one function is not very appealing!
I'll check out deegree

Comment: The same for deegree. It seems that I need to install all the environment in order to be able to use it. It's more for SDI environements.

Comment: I remember that deegree2 was used in desktop GIS "deejump" and jar was about 8 MB.

Comment: OpenJUMP Coordinate transformation plugin is using Geotools and filesize seems to be about 3.5 MB as zipped. It looks like you do not need to take all the 200 MB for one function. Check the references 
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jump-pilot/index.php?title=CTS_Extension_-_Working_with_Projections


http://sourceforge.net/projects/jump-pilot/files/OpenJUMP_plugins/GPS%2CCTS%20Extensions/

Comment: you don't need all of GeoTools for the conversion code - just referencing and one of the epsg modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lightweight library written fully in Java.

Coordinate Transformation Suite (abridged CTS) is a library developed to perform coordinate transformations using well known geodetic algorithms and parameter sets.

CTS handles 4257 coordinate reference systems (3910 EPSG).

The source code of this project is located at:

https://github.com/irstv/CTS

Comment: Do you've got an example using cts?

Comment: I don't see where CTS is used in OrbisGIS either.

Comment: CTS is used in H2GIS for the [ST_TRANSFORM](http://www.h2gis.org/docs/dev/ST_Transform/) SQL function. You have Java sample in the [wiki](https://github.com/irstv/CTS/wiki)